# PHP file download with no changes to the file

Tags: php, mp3, id3

I am trying to make a file download by using PHP but the file downloaded is a clean mp3 file without tags/metadata and not the one that is on my server.

Here's a detailed explanation:

I have a mp3 file with saved ID3 tags and all information on my server.

I run this code to start the download:

```
header('Content-Type: application/mp3');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.mp3"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile("file.mp3");
```

This starts a file download, but the file that is downloaded loses all its meta data, including any info and album art. Is there a way around this?

For example opening the file url and right clicking -> Save As, downloads it and preserves all the information stored in the file.

How can I prevent the deletion of all the metadata? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just add these two lines:

```
ob_end_clean();

flush();

readfile("file.mp3");
```

Comment: How would that differ from what the OP has in their question?